# Tagging master with git hooks before merging a branch to it

Tags: bash, git, github, gitlab, githooks

I understand there is no 'pre-merge' git hook but I was wondering if anyone had alternatives to suggest.

We use a master branch that we almost exclusively merge other branches (with lots of micro commits) into. We would like to automatically tag master as the current version (from a file) before the branch gets merged in.

Is there a way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by tagging from a file. Could you please clarify?

Comment: As in using git tag master v{version_number} where the version number is stored in a file as plaintext